# Express js:middleware function is not invoked

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

i am trying to implement middle ware function in my express js application it follows a simple MVC architecture.

`routes.js` under `route` folder

```
//load the controller auth.js
var auth = require('../controllers/auth');
//auth route
router.route('/auth').get(auth.simpleAuth);
```

`auth.js` under `controllers` folder

```
//load the middleware
var middleware = require('../middleware/middleware');

module.exports={
  simpleAuth:function (req,res) {
       //invoke middleware
        middleware.testMiddleware;
        res.send('middleware test completed');
    }
}
```

`middleware.js` under `middleware`  folder

```
module.exports={
    testMiddleware:function (req,res,next) {
        console.log('inside middleware');
        if(req.username == true){
            next();
        }else{
            console.log('auth failed')
        }

    }
}
```

There is no error message is shown but when i access `auth` route the middle ware function is not invoked.

Comment: please have a look at expressjs middleware https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking it properly. Try calling it from route.

**routes.js**

```
var middleware = require('../middleware/middleware');

router.route('/auth').all(middleware.testMiddleware).get(auth.simpleAuth);
```

**middleware.js**

```
testMiddleware: function (req,res,next) {
    console.log('inside middleware');
    if(req.username == true) {
        next();
    } else {
        // error
        return res.status(401).json({ "message" : "auth failed"});
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the meaning of `all`

Comment: It means, all types of http requests e.g. `GET`, `POST` will pass through the middleware.

Comment: it matches all HTTP verbs

Comment: Now it working one more question when the auth  failed i don't want to execute the` auth` route how is it possible??

Comment: pass an error in else block `else{
            console.log('auth failed')
            next('auth failed');
        }`

Comment: Updated the code with one possible answer. @p0k8_ suggestion is good too. For his solution, you need a global middleware for handling errors.

Comment: How about directly show the error message like else{ console.log('auth failed')  res.send('auth failed'); }

Comment: @Jabaa, please look at the expressjs middleware docs.. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html